# Parse XML on different levels

Tags: xml

How to get value session-id from this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xmldata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" status="SUCCESS">
<recordset name="login" check="1">
        <record name="login" id="12">
            <field name="session-identifier">77777777</field>
        </record>
</recordset>
</xmldata>
```

I use this but get only session-identifier and not 77777777

```
String XMLString = '<?xml version="1.0"?><xmldata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" status="SUCCESS"><recordset name="login" check="1"><record name="login" id="12"><field name="session-identifier">77777777</field></record></recordset></xmldata>';

DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
document.load(XMLString);
String taskId = document.getRootElement()
        .getChildElement('recordset', null)
        .getChildElement('record', null)
        .getChildElement('field', null)
        .getAttributeValue('name', null);
system.debug(taskId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `field` child element, the value is text not an attribute of XML child. Thus your code should look for text rather than attribute.

```
String XMLString = '<?xml version="1.0"?><xmldata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" status="SUCCESS"><recordset name="login" check="1"><record name="login" id="12"><field name="session-identifier">77777777</field></record></recordset></xmldata>';

DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
document.load(XMLString);
String taskId = document.getRootElement()
        .getChildElement('recordset', null)
        .getChildElement('record', null)
        .getChildElement('field', null).getText();
system.debug(taskId);
```

Comment: Thx it works - do we need specify session-identifier because in this section i have user-identifier

        <record name="login" id="12">
            <field name="session-identifier">77777777</field>
            <field name="user-identifier">8888888</field>
        </record>

Comment: tiny question - i have one more <field name="user-identifier">8888888</field> block

Comment: how to specify and get only from session-identifier